# Homebrew is up-to-date since one week

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am updating my home-brew on a daily basis. Sometimes every two days...
and overtime there is something what requires an upgrade. But since one week homebrew tells me it is up-to-date and now I am a bit curios if everything is alright. I have installed "rvm" about 2-3 weeks ago. but i also tried it with

"rum use system"

and nothing happens. It is still up-to-date.

Comment: Had a similar problem. You can fix that by manually updating with git: `cd /usr/local && git pull origin master`. After that normal updates should work again.

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/homebrew/brew#update-bug

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer I'll try it in the next hours when I'm back at my workspace. :-) will tell if it worked for me.

Comment: Solved the problem! Thank you! ;-)